# How to turn an LM741 op amp into a distorted portable guitar amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, distortion, voltage-clipping

Here is my circuit (to the best of my recollection):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVgTBw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOTE: *The voltages and resistance values are not known to me and what you see in the schematic is just default.*

## Features:

- Reverse feedback loop (I may mean "inverting" here)
- LM741 opamp from Texas Instruments
- Only two resistors used
- This is a clipping circuit

My question is two-fold:

1. What is the simplest configuration for building a headphone guitar amp using only an LM741 op amp and two resistors?
2. Any idea why mine died after only 2 days of use?

Comment: are you sure the voltage source describes your actual circuit? Also, neither R1 nor R2 make sense...

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller for your comment. No they don't make sense, and you will see I just made an edit to explain that. :) For that matter, I probably have the resistors in the wrong place also, but that's my best guess pulling from my dusty brain after 20 years of having those memories locked away.

Comment: This site is not a "forum".

Comment: The LM741 does still exist, but they're limited to use by hobbyists who don't know any better. The only thing they're useful for now is demonstrating op amp nonidealities, because they're very nonideal.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Huh? What do you mean? Stack Exchange is a network of niche-focused question and answer forums. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Felthry Thanks for explaining that ... I guess time always marches on. I bought my parts from Radio Shack when I was 19, but RS doesn't even exist as a hobbyist store anymore, now its mostly batteries and consumer electronics.

Comment: Please See - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums

Comment: There's several possbilities for what killed your 741 so many years ago.  Connecting the battery backwards, driving the headset directly from the opamp without a coupling capacitor (DC short circuit from output through the head phone,) etc.  No way to tell after over 20 years.

Comment: Thanks to this forum, I am getting served *advertisements* for TI LM741s. Thanks, guys.

Comment: Another problem with this question is about 85% of it should be deleted and boil it down to a single question. That may not be possible though unless this schematic can be cleaned up from the nonsense it is now.

Comment: I'd suggest that, while your personal introduction is nice, it belongs in your profile and not in a question. Please edit your question.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Based on the link you provided I can now see what you mean by forum. I meant it in the general sense, but in the more 'internet' sense, yes I'm glad this is NOT a forum because the practical answers well-thought-out questions is why these sites gain authority for developers, engineers, and others. So I guess this type of site can be more accurately called a `Q&A Community`?

Comment: The circuit you posted is most definitely not the circuit you used.  That do anything useful at all.

Comment: @JRE I think you hit on it! If I needed a capacitor for some kind of circuit protection and didn't have it (I didn't because I didn't know I needed it) I feel it very likely that that abscence could be what failed my circuit. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelKaras You are right about 85% of this question being unnecessary, I just thought it would help everyone to know that "I used to know the secret handshake" so to speak, but that I've been away from "the club" for several decades and forgot probably 80%. If you get my analogy. In any case, I'm just going to delete the question. Maybe I will post it with better wording later after I do some further research. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might do better to do a google search for "opamp guitar amp distortion". Then pick one that looks workable (has an explanation of the circuit, troubleshooting tips, etc.) and try it out.  If you don't understand the circuit(s), then come back here post the circuit and a link, and ask about the things that you don't get.

Comment: Don't worry. I edited it down for you. Clean up your schematic and you have a worthwhile question.

Comment: Ok @MichaelKaras I've posted a new schematic that I think makes more sense. See what you think. Thanks again.

Comment: It is a 741, it will always distort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage gain of the circuit that you now show is 2. Total of feedback resistors divided by the input resistor equals the gain. Depending upon the amplitude of the input voltage this may not offer as much clipping as you would like. You could increase the gain to 10 (feedback = 470K) and realize quite a bit more clipping for a lower level input signal.

Note that you may want to steer away from the antique relic of the LM741. These do not operate very well unless the power supplies are +15V and -15V and the output will clip at levels about 2.5V below the +supply and 2.5V above the -supply. There are plenty of other much better opamps that can operate very well on a single voltage supply of 9V or even 5V.

Comment: I think you nailed it Michael! In addition to probably needing some sort of capacitor on the output (for signal filtering?) The 10X gain makes more sense, as far as that seems closer to the actual values I might have used. Marking the answer as correct. Thanks for all your help. PS: Since you took the time to answer would you mind liking my post? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You example has a linear gain or -2 from Rf/Rin ratios if the source is low impedance and I concur is N.G.

For a bit more technical on simple distortion, read below from [**here**](https://www.passdiy.com/project/articles/audio-distortion-and-feedback) with simple examples.

### exerpt

> Many audiophiles believe that 2nd harmonic is to be preferred over 3rd harmonic. Certainly it is simpler in character, and it is well agreed that orders higher than third are more audible and less musical. However when given a choice between the sound of an amplifier whose characteristic is dominantly 2nd harmonic versus 3rd harmonic, a good percentage of listeners choose the 3rd.

( but  InterModulation (IM) distortion sounds nasty )

If you want to make a distorted note and draw it or choose different patterns and see the spectrum  go [**here**](http://www.falstad.com/fourier/) and choose [log Mag/phase view] and [sound] then drag freq slider.

Comment: Thanks for the links Tony! That gives me something to look into further.

Comment: I once fixed a buddies stat-of-the art ( circa late '70's) bass  synth that had a dozen special effects, flanger, fuzz bass, wah wah, etc in a tiny box of 2 dozen CMOS chips with part numbers erased because the designer made an error in level shifting 5V logic to bipolar supply CMOS analog switches that made it work marginally when new but fail soon after.  Awesome sounds.  Came from Silicon Valley used in Winnipeg.  Guitarist is now famous in LA. It basically used digital time delay filters and mixers , VCF's with chopped analog.

Comment: But if want distortion, any simple underbiased common emitter high gain cct will fuzz up any sound.